# How delegate the reverse DNS lookup to another name server?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, ptr-record

Consider this scenario:

1. A VPS server with one ip address (1.2.3.4) running "bind name server" to resolve requests.
2. An organization which gave that ip address to the VPS server. Obviously the organization is responsible for resolving the "reverse lookups".

Is there any way that the organization delegates resolving of that single IP to the VPS server? Suppose organization has the following in a file named "3.2.1.in-addr.arpa" :

```
@    IN    SOA    ns.organization.com. admin.organization.com. (
      ...
      ...
      )
     IN    NS     ns.organization.com.
1    IN    PTR    a.organization.com.
...
...
4    IN    PTR    theVPS.domain.               ;outside
```

I want to change this file in a way that "4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa" get resolved by the VPS. Is it possible at all?

I read RFC2317 but i'm not sure this is the case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Techically it's possible to delegate control of any subdomain to any authoritative name server i.e. `4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa. NS` could have your VPS. However, no-one really delegates reverse zones of single IPs, and it's unlikely they are willing to let a customer handle this by himself.

- Every zone needs at least two authoritative name servers. Your VPS is just a single name server. They would need to provide secondary server for that zone and configure zone transfers.
- Having an own zone for a single `PTR` record is overkill. The previous point is a clear example of that.
- The owner of the IP block won't like spoofing of false `PTR` records. Even if they let you choose your own reverse name, it's better to use some web configuration page that first checks that there really is a corresponding `A` record. Delegating control would make that impossible.
- Service providers have enough experience on the skill level of their customers to already know that you simply can't handle this. Better to mess with just the forward zones of your own domains. Asking this question proves this last point.